# Where I am making mistake in this matlab programme?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

Size of `X_new` is `5000x1`, `yedge` is `1x50`, and `N` is `1x49`.

Now, I am trying to run following programme:

```
for i=1:50  
    new = find(X_new>yedge, 1, 'last');
    N(new) = N(new)+1; 
end
```

But getting following error 'Matrix dimensions must agree' what is this and how can I solve this problem..?

Comment: I think you can compare only two matrices of same size or matrix elements to one number. What logic you want to use to compare 5000x1 vector to 1x5 vector?

Comment: well 5000x1 is my data and 1x50 (not 1x5) is my bin edge so basically with the help of binedge value I want to find out in which bin my data is coming from. like I want to do element wise operation. It is working with single data but not with different data.

Comment: What hapenned if you change `X_new>yedge` to `X_new>yedge(ii)` supposing loop defined as `for ii=1:length(yedge)`. `i` and `j` are imaginary units, so **be carefull** to override them.

Comment: Why not use [`discretize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html)?

Comment: Do not post blocks of code in comments, [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to reinvent the wheel, MATLAB's [`discretize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html) built-in returns the bin indices:

```
X = 1:10;
yedge = [0 4 8 10];

binidx = discretize(X, yedge);
```

Returning:

```
binidx =

     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     3     3     3
```

---

`discretize` was introduced in R2015a, but older versions of MATLAB have [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
X = 1:10;
yedge = [0 4 8 10];

[~, binidx] = histc(X, yedge);
```

Returning:

```
binidx =

     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     3     3     4
```

---

Note that `discretize` and `histc` define their bins differently. `discretize`, by default, includes the left bin edge, except for the last bin, which includes both bin edges. `histc` includes the left edge, but does not include the right edge. The last bin consists of the scalar value equal to last value in `yedge`.